Azure Logic App. "Execute CSharp Script Code" action. How to return data to workflow?
This page shows how to code a script:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/add-run-csharp-scripts#return-data-to-your-workflow
This page shows at "Returning data back to your workflow" a screen that's not present in the Logic App designer:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-integration-services-blog/announcement-introducing-net-c-inline-action-for-azure-logic/ba-p/4160541
I don't see any documentation or example of how to consume script results in a subsequent step.
I know it's a new feature. Can anyone explain how to consume results?

I have created a workflow with Execute CSharp Script Code action in standard logic app as shown below and have used the default code.


You can use var actionOutputs = (await context.GetActionResults("Compose").ConfigureAwait(false)).Outputs; to get the output of prior Compose action.
Then added Compose action to consume the output generated from Execute CSharp Script Code action.

Code-
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Compose": {
                "inputs": "@outputs('Execute_CSharp_Script_Code')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Execute_CSharp_Script_Code": [
                        "SUCCEEDED"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Execute_CSharp_Script_Code": {
                "inputs": {
                    "CodeFile": "execute_csharp_script_code.csx"
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "CSharpScriptCode"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "triggers": {
            "When_a_HTTP_request_is_received": {
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "kind": "Stateful"
}

I am sending the payload while triggering the workflow.

I am able to get the output generated from CSharp script.


If you want to get the value of message then use outputs('Execute_CSharp_Script_Code')['body'].

